# Move down multiple textView together

Tags: android

I have a program where I need to scrool down four TextView showing data about some players together, I can't use a single because it is anti aesthetic (personal opinion). there's a way to do it?
If someone can give me an XML layout example code I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any Screenshoot or sample image to show for better understanding.

Comment: I have four textView and I have to move all of then down together, I don't know how to setup the layout